# Name lookup with template class inheriting over namespaces

Tags: c++, templates

I finally managed to boil down my monolithic template library compilation failure to a simple test case. MSVC disagrees with Clang and GCC on the code being malformed, mostly due to name lookup. Unfortunately, I am not adept at reading the C++ specification, and I tend to believe Clang and GCC when it comes to conformance, but could you help me finding the relevant part of the specs so I may file a bug?

```
namespace A
{
    template <int _I, int _II>
    struct X {};
}

namespace B
{
    template <int _J>
    struct X {};

    // Clang: OK
    // GCC: OK
    // MSVC: OK
    template <int _K>
    struct Y
    {
        Y(const A::X<_K, _K>&,
          const X<_K>&) {}
    };

    // Clang: OK
    // GCC: OK
    // MSVC: ERROR
    template <int _K>
    struct Z : A::X<_K, _K>
    {
        Z(const A::X<_K, _K>&,
          const X<_K>&) {}
    };

    // Clang: ERROR
    // GCC: ERROR
    // MSVC: ERROR
    struct Q : A::X<1, 1>
    {
        Q(const A::X<1, 1>&,
          const X<1>&) {}
    };
}

int main()
{
    A::X<1, 1> ax;
    B::X<1> bx;

    B::Z<1> bz(ax, bx);

    return 0;
}
```

Three cases are:

1. Y is nothing extraordinary. It compiles fine with both compilers.
2. Compilation error stems from the second argument of Z's CTOR, X not having enough template arguments. It is up to name lookup to decide which X do I refer to. As far as I understood from reading [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), inheriting from a class should not bring in it's name into scope when it comes to unqualified name lookup.
3. If the class Q itself is not a template , all compilers reject it. Now this is the part where I completely lose ground. Why does it matter if the class is a template or not?

What is going on here?

Comment: Side note: You're using a bunch of reserved identifiers here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're running into is the *injected-class-name*. From [class]:

> The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.
>   For purposes of access checking, the *injected-class-name* is treated as if it were a public member name.

With unqualified lookup in a class definition, the first stop is in the scope of the class and its members. From [basic.lookup.unqual]:

> A name used in the definition of a class `X` outside of a member function body, default argument, *exception-specification*,
>   *brace-or-equal-initializer* of a non-static data member, or nested class definition shall be
>   declared in one of the following ways:
>   (7.1) — before its use in class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X` (10.2), or
>   (7.2) — [...]

We're looking for `X`. There is no `Q::X` (`Q`'s own scope) but there is an `A::X<1,1>::X` (base class scope), so lookup stops there and we never consider the enclosing namespace of `Q`. That's why we find `A::X<>` instead of `B::X<>`.

With `Z`, the situation is a little bit different. Now the base class is a *dependent* class template, and unqualified lookup will not look in dependent base classes. From [temp.dep]:

> In the definition of a class or class template, the scope of a dependent base class (14.6.2.1) is not examined
>   during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during
>   an instantiation of the class template or member.

So while the name `A::X<_K,_K>::X` exists, it is not considered, so lookup continues into the enclosing namespace and `B::X<>` is found.

In both cases, gcc/clang are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The gcc's error message provides the clue:

```
38 : error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
const X<1>&) {}
^
4 : note: provided for 'template<int _I, int _II> struct A::X'
struct X {};
^
```

> What is going on here?

A template class is not code. It's a recipe for creating code. two-phase lookup will handle the definition of `Z<>` when you use it (at which point there had better be an `X<i>` available).

`Q` is a concrete class, so there's no two-phase lookup involved. `X<i>` must exist at that point - and it doesn't.

As ever, clang and gcc are correct. MSVC is non-conforming.

Comment: Did you care to read the post? I understand what the error says. My question is WHY it thinks I am referring to A::X? I say X in the context of a class in namespace B that inherits from a class in namespace A. Why does X simply refer to A::X when unqualified lookup would suggest otherwise? And why does it matter if the class itself is a template or not?

Comment: @Meteorhead reworded.

Comment: So you are saying that two-phase lookup rule implies that syntax checking in the first pass must not check function names? Even if MSVC does not properly "skip" the first phase, both A::X and B::X have been parsed by the time the compiler reaches Z, so it has all the necessary info it needs to see nothing is fishy.

Comment: @Meteorhead the syntax must be correct when the template is parsed, as must anything that is known to exist.

Comment: `B::X<1>` exists at the point of `Q`... If you take the argument as `B::X<1>` instead of `X<1>`, the code compiles.

Comment: Yes, that is the workaround I found too. If I am explicit about the namespace, then it works. It just took 2 weeks of my time to track down the issue, and given how Clang and GCC agree, I would guess they are right about it, though having read a few articles myself, I do not find the clear indication to MSVC being wrong. Perhaps it took a different choice in doing something that is unspecified.